# Vertically center cell in a table with rotate-box

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rotating

I need help with vertical centering of the tabularx cells with text and rotatebox elements.

Here is my code (edit: updated the sniplets according to comment):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\smaller
\caption{A Table}
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llllllllllllXXXlX}

\multirow{2}{*}{} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Multi-1} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Multi-2} & 
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Multi-3}  \\

\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-17}

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{Ref}} & 

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-1}}& 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-3}}&
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-4}} & 

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-1}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-3}} &
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-4}} & 

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-1}} &
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-3}} & 

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{center} &  
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{center} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{center} & 

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox{90}{very-long-rotate-1}} & 

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{center} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-17}
                  &  &  &  &                &  &  &  &                  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &                 \\
              
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

and it renders the following table:

[image: table]

I want to have columns with text *center* vertically (as well as horizontally) center in the table.
Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: `\rotatebox[origin=c]` ... see graphicx manual pages 3-4.

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer I need @John Kormylo. I have also updated the code snippet.